# CodeXL cannot run GPU profile

Tags: windows, opencl, amd-gpu, codexl

I write an OpenCL program and want to profile it with codeXL. But the GPU : Performance Counters didn't work. The program is a very easy vector-add example and it runs properly on Visual Studio 2017. The codeXL displays cannot open `vecAdd.cl`, failed to create CL program from source. It is strange, who can give me some advice? The operating system is

- Windows 10 x64 pro,
- codeXL 2.5.67,
- AMD FirePro w7100,
- AMD APP SDK 3.0 x86.

[image: codeXL error message]

The `vecAdd.cl` is as follows:

```c
__kernel void vector_add(global const float *a, global const float *b,
    global float *result)
{

    int gid = get_global_id(0);
    result[gid] = a[gid] + b[gid];

}
```

Comment: Are you using OpenCL with the C-header or some other way?

Comment: The main program is written by C. and C-header just <stdio.h> <stdlib.h> <CL/cl.h> and <assert.h>. It is a simple program. The goal is to use GPU to calculate vector-add. a[1000] + b[1000]=c[1000]. I just suspect if I configure codeXL wrongly.

Answer (score 0):

OK，I have solved it. Because I set the wrong categories and codeXL cannot find the vecAdd.cl.

Comment: Which categories?

Comment: Presumably not categories, but folders.